# Not able to access Agora URLs

Tags: android, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm automating a website with Agora integrated. I have restricted network in virtual machine through which I'm trying to access the site but it's throwing error due to Agora external URLs accessed with public network. I have already made few sites accessible through machine but still no luck.
Please tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: It is showing error with the rtn.com and ports as wel..

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems like you have a firewall configured on your VM. You should configure your firewall to allow traffic from the SDK.
For RTC Web SDK 4.4.0 and later:

Domains

- `.agora.io`
- `.edge.agora.io`
- `.sd-rtn.com`
- `.edge.sd-rtn.com`

Ports

- TCP   Allow: `80; 443; 3433; 4700 - 5000; 5668; 5669; 6080; 6443; 8667; 9667; 30011 - 30013 (for RTMP converter)`
- UDP   Allow: `3478; 4700 - 5000 (2.9.0 or later); 10000 - 65535 (before 2.9.0)`

Visit the official [Agora Website](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/firewall) for the updated list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
Which IP's should i whitelist, your answer shows the domain and Ports. It is a restricted server. Can you let me know the IP's

Comment: Agora recommends whitelisting the domains instead of IPs, if that's not an option please open a support ticket (https://agora-ticket.agora.io/) to request the information about the IP addresses.

Comment: Raised a ticket for public IPs being used by agora, they have dynamic list of IPs which is frequently changing with every run, Domain whitelisting is not an option for me.

Thanks for your help @EkaanshArora